# Import module without running it

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Hi i am new to python/programming.
Is there a way to import a module into another and for it to not run unless called?
Or if there isn't a way to do so,import only variables from that module??

Comment: How can the variables exist if the script never runs?

Comment: modules dont run, functions do. If you import something and dont use it then fine

Comment: I need the module to run but in another file and have the variables stored so i can use it in another file...

Comment: This is what `if __name__ == '__main__'` is for. It won't do exactly what you're asking for, but it's a guard to stop certain parts of code running on import

Comment: Mind explaining how can i use it?I've seen it around this website while searching for an answer but i couldn't understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose you have a module `test.py` like this:

```py
def foo():
    print("hi")

foo() #This will print "hi" when you import the module
```

If you dont want to execute that, you cand add this:

```py
def foo():
    print("hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

With that, you are telling Python that your module only should run if you call `python test.py` (That is, the `test.py` file is the "main" module). But if you call it as module, the if wont execute.

Comment: def foo():
    print("hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()            This goes into the second module right??And where do i put it (beggining right under import or end below my code in the 2nd module)?

Comment: The `def foo()...` is just an example of a random function. The `if` statement goes inside the module you dont want to run unless another import it. For example, if you have `moduleA.py` and `moduleB.py`, and the moduleA imports the moduleB, you need to add the `if` on moduleB.

Comment: You can place the `if` at the end, just make sure to enclose all the function calls, or operations you want only occurr when the module is not an import (in the example, `foo()` was called inside the `if` so when import the module wont execute it).

Comment: But i do want to run the first module to get input from a user then that input is saved on a txt file.I want to use that input then on the second module..Does this work?

Comment: import sys
class Register:
 def Login():
  y_n = input("Would you like to register?\nType Yes/No:\n")
  if y_n == "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "ye" or "yea" or "ya" or "yEs" or "yeS" or "YEs" or "yES":
   cond = True
   if cond == True:
    name = open("login.txt" ,"w")
    Username = input("Username: ")
    Password = input("Password: ")
    name.write("User: "+Username)
    name.write("Pass: "+Password)
    name.close()
  elif y_n == "No" or "no" or "n" or "nO":
   cond = False
   if cond == False:
    sys.exit()
  else:
   print("Please choose between Yes or No")
   Login()

Comment: Login()    #another comment bcz no more char left

Comment: Yes! You only define a function `def work_with_input(some_input)` on the second module, and when you get the input on the first module, just need to call the `work_with_input` function (you imported the second module on the first, so you can use all the functions from the second module on the first module).

Comment: And in your case, yes it works. If the `login` functions is declared on the second module, and you imported it on the first module: `from second_module import *`, you can call the `login()` function without problem

Comment: Ok thank you guys!!Btw i want to learn how to make code that can be used IRL,so for exemple i want a timer to close the lights in my room at a certain hour.How would this be done/where could i learn??

Comment: This is out of the scope of your actual question. If you got your answer here can mark as solved and ask another question with respect of the IRL code :)

Comment: Dont worry, we all have a start. Happy coding :)

Comment: Am i allowed to post again if i can't manage to do it (if it's related to the OG question?)